# ERROR in src/app/logger.ts(18,16): error TS1005: '(' expected

Tags: angular

this is my class logger and the error here will be shown on setTimeout function-

```
export class logger{

    WriteLogger() {

        let dateTime,dd,mm,yyyy,h,m,s,m1,s1;
        console.log("logger class is called");
        //console.log(new Date().getCurrent);
        dateTime = new Date();
        dd = dateTime.getDate();
        mm = dateTime.getMonth() + 1;
        yyyy = dateTime.getFullYear();
        h = dateTime.getHours();
        m = dateTime.getMinutes();
        s = dateTime.getSeconds();
        m = this.checkTime(m);
        s = this.checkTime(s);

        setTimeout(( => {           
             console.log(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " The Current Time is " + h +":" + m + ":" +s);
        }),500);
    }
    checkTime(i){
        if(i<10){
            i = "0" + i;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> ERROR in src/app/logger.ts(18,16): error TS1005: '(' expected

Comment: It should be `setTimeout(() => {}, 500)` `()` signifies no parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be `self invoking`

Change `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(( => {
  console.log(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " The Current Time is " + h +":" + m + ":" +s);
}),500);
```

To

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " The Current Time is " + h +":" + m + ":" +s);
}, 500) ()
```